# Facebook not available from today

Tags: google-chrome, internet, internet-explorer, facebook

Till yesterday I was using facebook. There was no problems. When I tried to access facebook today it is not loading either in Google Chrome or IE. Both browsers can't load facebook. Chrome says 'this webpage is not available' and IE says 'this webpage can't be displayed'.

Why is facebook not available ? How can I solve this issue ?

I checked the host file in Windows/System32/Driver/etc. Nothing suspicious was there. I only found "127.0.0.1 localhost" there.

Is there any way to know whether something is blocking facebook in my laptop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you update and check your **AV status**? Checked for any suspicious **Add-ons** on the browsers? cleared browser **cookie/cache**? tried to run *browsers* in **SAFE** mode?Statuts of firewall- both windows and the one in the AV?

try ***pinging*** facebook.com and use **IP** to access facebook. Is m.facebook.com reachable? Also try this at 
*Command Prompt as Administrator*: `

1. ipconfig /flushdns
2. ipconfig /release
3. Ipconfig /renew
4. netsh winsock reset

Enter `TRACERT WWW.FACEBOOK.COM` at cmd prompt:
the last line MUST be *edge-star-shv-13-frc1.facebook.com [173.252.110.27]*

What *netsh winsock reset* command does are it resets Winsock Catalog to a clean state or default configuration. It removes all Winsock LSP (Layered Service Providers) previously installed, including the potential malfunctioned LSP that causes loss of network packets transmission failure.

Comment: Nice ideas, but both browsers are down. An addon could have installed itself in both browsers however... Another question is why would malware block Facebook?

Comment: @PlasmaPower at times, i have seen some add-ons or possible malwares block/cirumvent access to some social websites

Comment: @Tom could you check for any entries other than **127.0.0.1 localhost** in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.ini

Comment: In IE click tools and internet options. then connections and lan settings. remove the checkbox for 'use a proxy server'

Comment: I would +1 your post again for the `TRACERT` if I could, great job. I was looking up the command for that myself, I can never remember the name of the command.

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is in your browser. Go and check your browser compatibility with Facebook. Update your browser hope this will help you out.